# Talend's tOracleInput does not read data

Tags: sql, database, oracle, talend

My colleague created a project in Talend to read data from Oracle database. 
I used his project and so  I have his Job context with connection parameters to Oracle DB and Talend successfully connects on that computer.

I've created a trivial job which is composed of two components: `tOracleInput` which should be reading data and `tLogRow` which should be redirecting output to Talend's terminal.

The problem is that when I start the job - data is not outputted to terminal and instead of row amount outputted per second I see `Starting ...` status.

Would it be connection issues, inappropriate java version on my computer or something else?

Comment: if you're reading from a view it could take quite a few minutes until it starts to fetch the actual records. Till that you see Starting...

Comment: you can boost speed of tOracleInput by selecting advance setting, cursors option with limit

Comment: @BalazsGunics, exactly. Execution took approximately 7 minutes, and I have never waited for so long because I've thought there were connection errors. Thanks!

Comment: @andrew1993 phrased an answer out of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Starting...`  status means that the query is being executed. Usually it takes a few seconds to execute a simple query against the database. This is because of the Oracle database behavior that it starts to return the data without completing a full table scan. To use this feature you can use joins and filters, but not `group by` / `order by`.

On the other hand if you're using a view or executing a complex query, or just simply use `DISTINCT` it could happen that the query execution takes a few minutes. This is because the oracle database generates the `ResultSet` on the database side before returning the records.